# WPF UserControl Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing an extension for MS Visual Studio using WPF and I want to perform the drag and drop operation.
Now, I did it in a small WPF app to see if it is working and succeed, however when I did it in my extension, I cannot perform the action. Looks like the drop operation is not allowed.
When I tried GradOver/ DragEnter - everything works, however it is not good because those functions make many copies of what I would like to drag.
What could be a problem in your opinion?

PS
All Visual Studio extensions WPF controls inherent UserControl and not from Window as a regular WPF app.

Here is some of the code examples:

Drag Operation:

```
<Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="box1_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

Drop Operation:

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True" Drop="box2_Drop"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Those two XAML tags hold pretty much zero functionality, so my guess is something in the event handlers is not working as it is supposed to. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why zero functionality? I wrap everything in the dragdrop container inside. The question is "how do I allow dragdrop operation in usercontrol?"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-user-control

Comment: can you share what you got in your box1_MouseLeftButtonDown and box2_Drop methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is in this post, very short and helpful:
[Drag Drop Within WPF ToolWindow in VS2010 Extension Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158116/drag-drop-within-wpf-toolwindow-in-vs2010-extension-not-allowed)
This answer is for MSVS2010, however worked also in 2015